# Convert dynamic svg-tag to image

Tags: php, svg

I have a `.php` file where some calculations are taking place to how the svg is going to look, giving different classes when conditions are met.

```
<circle class="fill-red<?= getOpacity($number_4, 'small') ?>" data-name="small" cx="217.41" cy="156.51" r="2.33"/>
```

Php calculation for type small:

```
case 'small':
    if ($number == 0) {
        return ' hidden';
    } elseif ($number < 15) {
        return ' light';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
    break;
```

When all calulations are done the php file only shows the svg-tag but I'm having troubles trying to make it into an images **keeping the edits** that where made to them dynamically through the controller (the numbers are set in the controller, the file only knows what variable to call).

Copying the file and giving it `.svg` doesn't work due to the inline php code.

`file_get_contents` also doesn't work since the variables don't get passed.

Also trying to do it without `Imagick` first as I have no idea how it works

Comment: show the output `svg` tag?

Comment: The output is dynamic alex like I mentioned I can't simply put '.svg' at the end, already tried that. Are you asking for the svg with php code or the result of that?

Comment: If you're outputting markup, try using the output buffer to get the markup as a string, and `file_put_contents` to write it to a .svg file. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php